# C++ Input Validation for Whole Number. The input for num should not be a char/string, a decimal value, or a negative number

Tags: c++, validation, input

for some reason this only gets validation for char/string.
How to make it validate negative and decimal values?

```
cout << "Please enter a whole number: ";
while (!(cin >> num || num < 0)){ 
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    cout << "Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.     \n";
    cout << "Please enter a whole number again: ";
    cin >> num;
```

Comment: Depends how far you wanna take it. Normally the approach is to read a whole line with `std::getline` and then either parse value(s) out with `std::istringstream` or call `std::strtol` and check the beginning/end position. Then you need to decide whether whitespace is okay, and/or if you want to read a whole line, because these considerations can make things slightly more fiddly. You could just read a `std::string`, which takes care of whitespace. You could even use `std::regex` to validate the input, then use `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some problems with your code :

1. no need to write `cin >> num` 2 times , it's only enough to get the input only once in the condition of the while loop
2. it's not `!(cin >> num || num < 0)` , it's `!(cin >> num) || num < 0` as `!(cin >> num)` will report the input of string while `num < 0` will report the input of negative value
3. since entering a decimal value , the `cin` will store the value till the `.` and leave the remaining digits with `.` in the buffer not consumed them , then you can add the condition `cin.peek() == '.'` to check if the user entered a decimal value

this is the edited code of yours:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a whole number: ";
    while (!(cin >> num) || num < 0 || cin.peek() == '.') {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.     \n";
        cout << "Please enter a whole number again: ";
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is some example output:

```
Please enter a whole number: asdasd
Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.
Please enter a whole number again: -12312
Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.
Please enter a whole number again: 1.23
Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.
Please enter a whole number again: -123.2
Invalid! A whole number is positive and an integer.
Please enter a whole number again: 123

C:\Users\abdo\source\repos\Project55\Debug\Project55.exe (process 31896) exited with code 0.
```